# Ввод текста в поле input и поиск блоков на странице с нужным значением

Tags: javascript, jquery

нужно чтоб после ввода текста в поле input и клика Enter был переход на страницу search.html и на ней появлялись скрытые блоки со значением в input, переход осуществляется но выборка не проходит, подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка? Заранее благодарю.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#input').keyup(function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    window.location = 'search.html' 
                    {   var  value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                        $('.block-display-none').filter(function() {
                        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase());
                        });
                    };
                };
            });
        });
```

Comment: сохраняйте значение в localstorage и оттуда берите при загрузке страницы search

Comment: Ошибка в том, что скрипт остался на предыдущей странице. Вы же никак не передаёте на страницу search.html данные, которые были введены в инпут.